# Ethernet transformer RX Centre tap connection to ground

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, current, ethernet, poe

I was going through some schematics that would have a PoE application and stumbled upon the below portion of a PoE camera application schematic.

[image]

In the above schematic, we can see the R66 resistor is present which makes the Rx centre tap connection to ground.

Below is the pinout for the ethernet camera connector:

[image]

My question is

1. Is this Receive centre tap pulled to ground, a correct connection?
   Even tx centre tap is also pulled to ground but it is not populated.

Any idea whether this is right?
If not, any idea on Why Receive centre tap shouldn’t pulled to ground, any specific reason?

Comment: You don't know which ground symbol that is based on the schematics alone. Even if it is a ground symbol, it could be an isolated ground. And it might be okay even if it is unisolated ground, or it might be incorrectly designed non-compliant device. The picture does not contain any information to judge that.

Comment: @Justme, from the portion, the Chassis ground is different from the board PCB ground. The RX Centre tap is grounded to the PCB ground

Comment: That is apparent from the schematics. That informatiom can't be used to answer your question though. The TX and RX centre taps carriy positive and negative supply from POE. They need to connect to somewhere if you want to use PoE. The schematics don't tell how it is used.

Comment: @Justme, Ok, can you tell me what information you need from the schematics?

Comment: If that ground is isolated or not. Where does it go to? I mean, for example, if you have a metal or plastic device with live mains wiring inside it, it does not need isolation if no one can touch it. But if a device has external connections or user touchable parts then it needs to have isolation.

Comment: @Justme The ground connected to RX Centre tap is also connected to chassis ground via a 100pF 630V capacitor.

Comment: Where did the schematic come from?